# How to use BlocBuilder to refresh a Dialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit, flutter-dialog, flutter-cubit

I have a dialog and I wrap it in a blocbuilder to update it according to the type of state but the dialog just is built First time and after state has changed it doesn't rebuild.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) {
  BlocBuilder<ExampleCubit, ExampleState>(
      bloc: cubit,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return CustomDialog(
          title:"title",
          onSave: (File file) {
            cubit.uploadImage(file);
          },
          progress: (state is ExtendedExampleState)? state.progress:0,
          onDelete: () {},
          onCancel: () {
             cubit.cancelUploading();
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Note: It is important to use Bloc pattern rather `StateFulBuilder`.

Comment: please share your CustomDialog code.

Comment: please share `Example Cubit` and `Example State` and `Custom Dialog` . Current Information is not Enough

Comment: the problem is that the builder of BlocBuilder doesn't recall when it is in builder of show dialog and my cubit and state don't matter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `BlocBuilder` in `Dialog` so that it gets rebuilt every time there's a change. For that to work, you also need to pass the current cubit(bloc) using `BlocProvider.value`.

```
  // Get the cubit(bloc) instance
  final exampleCubit = context.read<ExampleCubit>();

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      // Provide the existing cubit(bloc) instance to the new route (the dialog)
      return BlocProvider<ExampleCubit>.value(
        value: exampleCubit,
        child: CustomDialog(
            //... your implementation
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

And now, make sure that you're using `BlocBuilder` in `CustomDialog`, like so:

```
class CustomDialog extends StatelessWidget {

  const CustomDialog({
    Key? key,  
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ExampleCubit, ExampleState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        // rebuild widget...
      }
    )
  }
```

With this setup, the dialog gets updated using bloc.